# Gradle include all files under a directory ('recursively')

Tags: c++, gradle

So I've been making a Java project using Gradle ([GitHub](https://www.github.com/orbyfied/spruce)), but it uses/needs JNI (natives).

I was first using Makefiles to compile and link the C++ code, but then I found out how to compile and link C++ natives using Gradle, so I got all of that working. But now I am stuck, because I can't find a way to include all natives, on the same level (base) **inside** of the JAR file.  **NOTE:** *I don't need help with compiling the natives, only with including/packaging them.*

> **EDIT:** I just commited the changes to GitHub.

**This is my directory structure:**

```
[Project Directory]
 - build.gradle
 - src/
 - win32/ (the only native library that i currently have)
     - cpp/
 - main/
     - java/
 - build/
   - libs/ (here is the JAR and the natives)
     - win32/ (the natives)
       - shared/ (the dynamic link libraries, i only want these)
          - x64/ (i want to include both x64 and x86)
             - mylibrary.dll (just the DLLs should be included)
             - mylibrary.ext
             - mylibrary.lib
          - x86/
```

**So there are a few criteria:**

- I only want the DLL files, none of the `.ext` and `.lib` stuff.
- I want to be able to dynamically change the amount of libraries and the names of the natives.

**What I have tried:**

My first attempt was just looping through all folders. I didn't have to use recursion because the depth of the file structure is fixed, so it will never be further from or closer to the `build/libs` directory. This is how I tried coding it:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/resources"

            // include natives
            String libfp = "${buildDir}/libs/"
            File   libf  = new File(libfp);
            if (!libf.exists())
                libf.mkdir();

            FileFilter isDir = f -> f.isDirectory();
            FileFilter isDll = f -> f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".dll");

            for (File file : libf.listFiles(isDir)) { // iterate "libs" to find all libraries
                // enter "shared"
                File filen = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/shared/"); 
                for (File file1 : filen.listFiles(isDir)) { // iterate over "shared" to find all platforms
                    for (File file2 : file1.listFiles(isDll)) { // get all dlls
                        include(file2.getAbsolutePath())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked, except from the including itself. I don't know if I understand how this works correctly, but the `include` function didn't seem to add anything to the resources.

Then, I checked the documentation and found it was a pattern based function, so I tried making a simple `include` call with the pattern I thought would work:

```
include "/build/libs/**/*.dll"
// I also tried the following:
include "/build/libs/**.dll"
include "/build/libs/*.dll"
```

But that didn't seem to work too. So I think I am just misunderstanding how the `include` function works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
include '/build/libs/**'
```

will work. Thanks.